# Military Discounts PHP

Tags: php, discount

The goal is to make a discount system in php for (us) military personel.I have searched the web for some sort of api to check a military service number of some kind but couldn't find one. What is the best way to implement this automatically. Manually checking the numbers is not an option because that will delay the transaction unless it the only possible way.

Comment: ask pentagon for the api? lol

Comment: there is an api for this: https://www.dmdc.osd.mil/appj/scra/scraHome.do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the nature of your business the easiest way would be to establish identity upon account creation using military ID or something similar. For  what I'm assuming is security reasons there is no known system to check validity of a service claim programmatically.

Comment: As noted, there is a DoD resource that allows for the verification of service claim.  It exists due to a federal law that protects servicemembers from foreclosure while in an active duty status.